# Formatting String to Date in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, date

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I can't for the life of me solve it.

I have a JSON object as so:

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57cb5aac9bd9a31100c793d1"
    },
    "reminders": [
        "2014-03-12T12:00:00",
        "2014-03-12T13:37:27",
        "2014-03-12T13:37:27",
        "2014-03-12T22:14:27"
    ],
    "user": "xxx"
}
```

I want to parse the date from the reminders is JS to a date object in a loop, as so.

```
for (var i = userSchedule.reminders.length - 1; i >= userSchedule.reminders.length - 1; i++)
    {
    var date = new Date(userSchedule.reminders[i]);
    }
```

But it just displays invalid date whenever I log it. Any ideas?

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor is not recommended since it's largely implementation dependent. You might get away with it in node.js, but don't try it in a browser. "2014-03-12T12:00:00" should be treated as local per ES5+, but current Safari 9 (at least) treats it as UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something here is not as it seems, because calling the date constructor in both Chrome and Node.JS returns the correct date for me. I also tried it in the JSBin below.

https://jsbin.com/fomagugiwe/edit?html,output

I would log the value going into the date constructor, just to ensure that the value being used is of the correct format. Could you also provide the Node version you are using for this script for further testing..

Comment: I did the same and all works. I think the error was solved, and it was a wrong loop which never iterate over the array because it's stop condition would never be achieved.

Answer (score 4):

Though its not answer but why have you used  `user_schedule.reminders` and `userSchedule.reminders` and your for loop  will loop only once with correct data since your loop begins with **i=3;** which is index for last element of `userSchedule.reminders[3]` and when you loop next it will go beyond the scope of your array reminders

Answer (score 1):

for date time manipulation I strongly recommend using http://momentjs.com

where you can do

```
moment("your date string")
```

Or

```
moment("your date string","your date format")
```

Comment: MomentJS seems like a sledgehammer response to a simple javascript date problem like this.

Comment: MomentJS is a good thing if the date will be used in some processing that depends of timezone, like scheduled tasks. In this case, I think it's more than he needs.

Comment: This is not an answer. It doesn't explain the OPs issue or why the answer fixes it.

Comment: He asked how to parse the string to date and If this method can solve his problem then it is a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is broken, it seems you're trying to iterate from `0` to `userSchedule.reminders.length - 1`, so:

```
for (var i=0; i < userSchedule.reminders.length; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Also, parsing date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is not recommended due to variances in implementations. You should parse the string manually, a library can help but isn't necessary if you have only one format to parse.

A date string like "2014-03-12T12:00:00" should be treated as "local" (i.e. the host time zone offset should be used when calculating the time value), however not all implementations will do that. A small library like [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) makes it simple:

```
var d = fecha.parse('2014-03-12T12:00:00','YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm-ss');
```

You can also use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), but it's likely overkill for what you need. There are many other parsing and formatting libraries available that are suitable too.